# Function to convert "path" into regular expression

Tags: php, strings, regex

This function converts a string like:
`/{?lang(2-5):lowercase}/{page(2+):lowercase}/{article}-{id:integer}*.html*`
Into the following regular expression:
`@^(?J)/(?:(?P<lang>[a-z\d\-_\W]{2,5})/)?(?P<page>[a-z\d\-_\W]{2,})/(?P<article>[\w\W]*?)\-(?P<id>[1-9]*?).*?\.html.*?$@`
Ready to be used somewhere else, using `preg_match()`.

The basic structure is as follows:

- Everything is between brackets (`{...}`)
- The next character can be a `?`, to define it as optional
- Then comes the name of the "item" to capture
- Between parenthesys, you can specify the length. Lengths can be a single number (to meant "exactly this long"), an interval (`2-5`) or an interval without upper limit (`2+`).
- You can say the type you want. It can be integer, 0-integer, lowercase, uppercase and (if unspecified) defaults to case insensitive.

This function converts the info there into a regular expression, usable with `preg_match`.

```php
<?php

function convertPathToRegex($path){
    // (?J) -> repeated names in capturing groups (the J modifier is only for PHP 7.2+)
    static $regex = '@(?J)\{
        (?P<optional>\?)? #defined if it is optional
        (?P<item>[a-z]\w*) #item name
        (?:\(
            (?P<length>[1-9]\d*) # fixed length (default), or minimum length
            (?P<length_max>
                \+ # no maximum length
                |-[1-9]\d* # specific maximum length
            )?
        \))?
        (?:
            # types are used as :<type>
            \:(?P<type>
                (?:0\-)?int(?:eger)? # treats as an integer (starting from 0 or 1)
                |num(?:ber)? # same as 0-int
                |[lu]c(?:ase)? # [l]ower or [u]pper case
                |(?:low|upp)er(?:case)? # lower, upper, lowercase, uppercase
            )
        )?
    \}
    |(?P<item>
        \* # any case insensitive text
    )@x';

    // default options
    static $default = array(
        'optional' => '',
        'item' => '*',
        'type' => 'ci',
        'length' => 0,
        'length_max' => 0
    );

    // types to be used on {name:type}
    static $types = array(
        '0-int' => '\d',
        'int' => '[1-9]',
        'ci' => '[\w\W]',
        'lc' => '[a-z\d\-_\W]',
        'uc' => '[A-Z\d\-_\W]',
    );

    // alternative names for $types
    static $types_map = array(
        '' => 'ci',
        'integer' => 'int',
        '0-integer' => '0-int',
        'num' => '0-int',
        'number' => '0-int',
        'lcase' => 'lc',
        'lower' => 'lc',
        'lowercase' => 'lc',
        'ucase' => 'uc',
        'upper' => 'uc',
        'uppercase' => 'uc'
    );

    // will contain all the into about the {items}
    $items = array();

    $format = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches)use(&$default, &$types, &$types_map, &$items){
        $item = array_merge($default, $matches);

        // the default is to select any text
        if($item['item'] === $default['item'])
        {
            $items[] = '.*?';

            // return %s to be used later with sprintf
            return '%s';
        }

        $regex = '(?P<' . $item['item'] . '>';
        $piece = isset($types_map[$item['type']])
            ? $types[$types_map[$item['type']]]
            : $types[$item['type']];

        if($item['type'] === 'int')
        {
            if($item['length'] >= 2)
            {
                // must subtract 1 from length and length_max to compensate for the [1-9] (1 char) at the beginning
                $piece .= '\d{' . ($item['length'] - 1) . (
                    $item['length_max']
                        ? ',' . (
                            $item['length_max'] !== '+'
                                ? abs($item['length_max'] - 1)
                                : ''
                        )
                        : ''
                    ) . '}';
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                    if a length exists, it must be lower than 2 (1 char)
                        so, nothing else needs to be done ($piece contains [1-9], which matches 1 char)

                    if no length is provided, match all the numbers ahead
                */
                $piece .= $item['length'] ? '' : '\d*';
            }
        }
        else if($item['length'] >= 2 || ($item['length_max'] && $item['length_max'] !== '+'))
        {
            /*
                only give it a length specification if and only if the length is 2 or higher
                    or if there's a maximum length
                this means that (1) and (1+) are skipped, but (1-5) returns {1,5} (regex)
            */
            $piece .= '{' . $item['length'] . (
                $item['length_max']
                    ? ',' . (
                        $item['length_max'] !== '+'
                            ? abs($item['length_max'])
                            : ''
                    )
                    : ''
                ) . '}';
        }
        else if(!$item['length'] || ($item['length'] === '1' && $item['length_max'] === '+'))
        {
            // if no length is specified (or is 1+), it means "all"
            $piece .= '+';
        }
        /*
            length of 1 doesn't need any treatment
            this is because $piece contains the specification for 1 character already
        */

        $regex .= $piece . ')';

        $items[] = $item['optional'] ? '(?:' . $regex . ')?' : $regex;

        // returns %s to be used with sprintf
        return '%s';
    }, $path);

    // all arguments must be in the same array, can't do $format, $items
    $new_regex = call_user_func_array(
        'sprintf',
        array_merge(
            array(preg_quote($format, '@')), // protects special chars, like periods and slashes
            $items
        )
    );

    return '@^(?J)' . str_replace(')?/', '/)?', $new_regex) . '$@';
}
```

It is a pretty complicated and quite massive.

I've decided to do not implement any memoization scheme, as this function is part of a larger project and this will be cached outside.

This function works as intended, as far as I could tell and from my testing.

Is there anything I can improve in this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one thing that jumps out at me as whacky...

```
[a-z\d\-_\W]
```

[Regex101 breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/pyrg9A/1/)

I think this means to match a lowercase substring, but that's not what it is doing.

Since `\W` is the inverse of `\w` and because `\w` represents `A-Za-z0-9_`, I think it is strange that the subpattern is used to replace the lowercase placeholder.

As is, your pattern can be expanded to the following equivalent:

```
(?:[a-z0-9_\-]|[^A-Za-z0-9_])
```

This is far, far more characters than `a-z`.  If I was new to using your system, I would expect `lowercase` to exclusively mean `[a-z]`.

I mean if you were simply trying to deny uppercase substrings (and allow everything else) at that position, why wouldn't you use a negated character class `[^A-Z]`.

And as I say that, I ask if the placeholder itself is flawed.  Perhaps more intuitive to make a `not` keyword/placeholder to be written as `notupper` or `not:upper` or maybe `!upper` if you need such functionality.

I guess what I am saying is, you should either adjust your placeholders' respective patterns, or change the placeholder terminology.

Less of a concern, but perhaps something worth sharing is that most patterns that intend to match any character (including newlines) will either use `[\S\s]` or `.` with the `s` pattern modifier.  Your `[\w\W]` works the same, just not commonly used.

Comment: You made very good points. Yes, it is flawed, and the idea is to match *all* lowercase or uppercase characters. Problem is, there's so many of them. The idea was to try to match them all. Also, I'm not terribly worried about newlines. For it's use, newlines aren't supposed to exist. I should have used `.` instead of `[\w\W]`. The "placeholders" are flawed, and in need of tweaking.

Comment: When you say "all" lowercase|uppercase, are we talking about multibyte characters?    I don't see a `u` flag on the end of your pattern.  If so, you should also read about Unicode Categories at https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Yeah, I've always had troubles making those work, for some reason. But I've tried with your suggestion (using `\p{...}`), and it worked.... I guess I was doing something wrong before. For the use I have, I believe that the next version I've made is superior, but longer and harder to read.